# Handling Advantage Database Server by Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVP3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, advantage-database-server

I need to handle Advantage Database Server(ADS Ver.9.1) by Entity Framework in ASP.net MVC3 environment.

I already spent almost 2 weeks only for this :(  but still I couldn't find the answer.

To get right advice, I will try to show step by step how and what I did. so If you find some mistake I made or you know something I can try then, please advice me. plz..

Firstly, I created a TEST table in ADS.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( 
      ID AutoInc,
      Name CIChar( 50 )) IN DATABASE;
```

and define ID as primary key.

[image]

And I tried to access this table using Console Application.

Using Visual Studio 2010, create new console Application (C#)

and I typed like this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Advantage.Data.Provider;

namespace Ads_Console_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection("Data Source=\\\\10.0.111.4:6262\\20090622\\SHK\\SHK.ADD;ServerType=REMOTE;User ID=AdsSys;Password=XXXXX;");
            AdsCommand cmd;
            AdsDataReader reader;
            int iField;

            try
            {
                // make the connection to the server
                conn.Open();

                // create a command object
                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                // specify a simple SELECT statement
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from TEST";

                // execute the statement and create a reader
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // dump the results of the query to the console
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (iField = 0; iField < reader.FieldCount; iField++)
                        Console.Write(reader.GetValue(iField) + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // close the reader (can’t execute other statements
                // on this command or connection) until it is closed
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (AdsException e)
            {
                // print the exception message
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

and run, then it connect to ADS successfully and get the data too.

[image]

As you see, The table has 3 rows.

NoW,

I will try to access ADS using Entity Framework. (MVC3)

I create new project with MVC3 Framework. and selected Empty Template.

[image: I create new project with MVC3 Framework. and selected Empty Template.]

And add Advantage.Data.Provider to Reference.

[image]

Next, I Modified Web.Config(root) file, add connectionStrings.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFAdsContext" connectionString="Data Source=\\10.0.111.4:6262\20090622\SHK\SHK.ADD;ServerType=REMOTE;User ID=adsSys;Password=XXXXX;
         TrimTrailingSpaces=True;" providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And, I craeted 3 class into the Models folder.

1. EFAdsContext.cs
2. TestRepository.cs
3. TEST.cs

Here is the codes,

**1. EFAdsContext.cs**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;


    namespace Ads_test_mvc3.Models
    {
        public class EFAdsContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<TEST> TEST { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**2. TestRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ads_test_mvc3.Models
{
    public class TestRepository
    {
        private EFAdsContext context = new EFAdsContext();

        public IQueryable<TEST> test
        {
            get { return context.TEST; }
        }
    }
}
```

**3. TEST.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Ads_test_mvc3.Models
{
    public class TEST
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And create HomeControllers.cs into Controllers folder.

**HomeControllers.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ads_test_mvc3.Models;

namespace Ads_test_mvc3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {

            TestRepository tests = new TestRepository();
            int cnt = tests.test.Count();


            ViewBag.cnt = cnt;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

And Finally Add View for HomeController

/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


Cnt : @ViewBag.cnt
```

And RUN this application,

[image]

then, I get this error message. =3

It's long writing I know, but I tried to write as much detail as I could.

If anybody knows how to solve this problem, please please advise me.

Thank you!

[Stack Trace]

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +9619597
   Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType) +1150
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, DbTableColumnMetadata tableColumnMetadata, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType, Boolean isKeyProperty) +60
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.PropertyMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, IEnumerable`1 properties, DbEntitySetMapping entitySetMapping, DbEntityTypeMappingFragment entityTypeMappingFragment, IList`1 propertyPath, Boolean createNewColumn) +1293
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.EntityTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +496
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(EdmModel model, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +122
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel model) +30
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +189
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +453
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +57
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +50
   Ads_test_mvc3.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ads_test_mvc3\Ads_test_mvc3\Controllers\HomeController.cs:20
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969117
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Do you have provider registered in web.config or machine config?

Comment: Thank you for comment, Could you tell me how to check that? I just downloand the provider from http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=13&Product=4&Platform=11 . and instill it. I am testing only on local station (Not on server).

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I just add Stacktrace, thank U